# Show that $\lim\limits_{z\to -1} \frac{z^2}{1+z} = \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $$\lim_{z\to -1} \dfrac{z^2}{1+z} = \infty$$

I can prove that $z = -1$ is a pole using the Laurent series and hence $\lim_{z\to -1} \dfrac{z^2}{1+z} = \infty$.

But I am having difficulty showing it by the $M-\delta$ definition.

Some help on how to prove it using $M-\delta$ definition please?

Comment: You can't show it because it isn't true. Approaching from the right on the real axis gives $\infty$, but approaching from the left on the real axis gives $-\infty$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic $z=-1$ is a pole.

Comment: That is true, but irrelevant. Just because $z=a$ is a pole of $f(z)$ doesn't mean $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$. Did you not read my first comment?

Comment: You might be actually asked to prove that, in the  complex plane, $$\lim_{z\to -1} \left|\frac{z^2}{1+z}\right| = +\infty$$ and *that* is rather direct, no?

Comment: @Did there is no modulus sign.

Comment: Just trying to make sense of your question... As others already explained, with no modulus sign the result is **wrong** (already on the real line, by the way).

Comment: @symplectomorphic Section 77 of Churchill Complex Variables and Applications, states that if $z_0$ is a pole of a function $f$, then $lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty$.

Comment: Let me suggest to compute $$\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{(-1+t)^2}{1+(-1+t)}$$ and $$\lim_{t\to0-}\frac{(-1+t)^2}{1+(-1+t)}$$ for $t$ real, then, just to get a grip on what happens.

Comment: Churchill is most probably referring to the statement in my comment. With the modulus. Of course.

Comment: @LittleRookie It would appear that your book is using the concept of a point at infinity (probably with modulus). Ok, well your function has a pole at $z = -1$. Now what? Are there examples? What have your tried to do?

Comment: Wittgenstein to Sraffa: "I wish to say one more thing. I think that your fault in a discussion is this: YOU ARE NOT HELPFUL! I am like a man inviting you to tea in my room, but my room is hardly furnished; one has to sit on boxes, and the teacups stand on the floor, and the cups have no handles, etc., etc. I hustle about fetching anything I can think of to make it possible that we should have tea together. You stand there with a sulky face, say that you can't sit down on a box and can't hold a cup without a handle, and generally make things difficult. At least that's how it seems to me."

Comment: @symplectomorphic Just to clarify, I have never intended to offend you or doubt your intellect. I am given this definition by my Prof and it seems like it is different from what it should be. Furthermore, I am an undergrad with no pre-knowledge on Complex analysis. And i assume most undergrad would assume the material taught by his/her Prof. is correct at first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a pole means $|f(z)|\to+\infty$ not $f(z)\to+\infty$.

Now if you take $z=u-1$ with $|u|<\delta$ then

$|f(z)|=\left|\dfrac{u^2-2u+1}{u}\right|=\left|u-2+\dfrac 1u\right|\ge\left|\dfrac 1{|u|}-|u-2|\right|\ge \dfrac 1\delta-2-\delta\quad$  (for $\delta\ll 1$)

And this is an unbounded quantity when $\delta\to 0$.

---

You may want to look at that answer by M.Hardy.

[What's the difference between Complex infinity and undefined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420557/whats-the-difference-between-complex-infinity-and-undefined)

In fact if we define a complex point at infinity $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, then we can speak about things like $z\to\infty$ but keep in mind that it means $|z|\to+\infty$ from the standard point of view.

So when your book says $\lim\limits_{z\to-1} f(z)=\infty$ it refers to that particular infinite.

It doesn't change the fact that in practice what you have to prove is $\lim\limits_{z\to-1} |f(z)|=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you have to show that $\lim_{z\to -1} \left|\frac{z^2}{1+z}\right| = \infty$.

Let $M>0$. Since $\left|\frac{1+z}{z^2}\right| \to 0$  for $z \to -1$, there is $ \delta >0$ such that

$\left|\frac{1+z}{z^2}\right| <1/M$ for $0<|z+1|< \delta$.

Can you proceed ?